# How to assign an empty value to a variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

If `firewall_allowed_ports` in:

```
- name: port {{ item }} allowed in firewall
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: "{{ item }}"
    proto: tcp
  with_items: 
    - 22
    - "{{ firewall_allowed_ports }}"
```

is undefined, then this error occurs:

```
fatal: [host.example.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' 
has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined.
```

**Attempt to solve the issue**

```
"{{ firewall_allowed_ports | }}"
```

results in:

```
fatal: [host.example.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error
while templating string: expected token 'name', got 'end of print statement'. 
String: {{ firewall_allowed_ports | }}"}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `default([])` to create an empty list if `firewall_allowed_ports` is undefined. The `with_items` will skip it when empty.

```
- name: port {{ item }} allowed in firewall
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: "{{ item }}"
    proto: tcp
  with_items: 
    - 22
    - "{{ firewall_allowed_ports | default([]) }}"
```