# Set array as default value in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to set a default array if a variable is empty. Setting an empty array in the defaults filter works described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/805576/how-to-assign-an-empty-value-to-a-variable-in-ansible).
Setting an array which is stored in a variable does not.

In the example `run_targets` is `undefined`, `targets` should be used instead.

```
- name: Set vars
  vars:
    targets: [target1, target2, target3]

- name: Include run sql task
      include: tasks/sql.yml
      with_items: "{{ run_targets | defult(targets) }}"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Your playbook is not valid. `vars` is not a module that you can run in a task. You either use `set_fact` or declare `vars` at play level. The following complete example demonstrates that it works without problems:

```
---
- name: Demo of default from var
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    default_targets:
      - target1
      - target2
      - target3

  tasks:
    - name: Show run targets else defaults
      debug:
        msg: "{{ run_targets | default(default_targets) }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Demo of default from var] ************************************************

TASK [Show run targets else defaults] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "target1",
        "target2",
        "target3"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "{run_targets: [a,b,c]}"

PLAY [Demo of default from var] ************************************************

TASK [Show run targets else defaults] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```